# Access Angular module defined in a different .js file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

How do I access a angular module that is defined in a different .js file ?

Background:

I kind of started angular js programming (within an ASPNET MVC app) getting-started guide.

For sake of clarity, I have created a angular module in a file called `AspnetMvcAngular.js` file.

`var AspnetMvcAngularJs = angular.module('AspnetMvcAngularJs', []);`

I then, defined the angular controller code in a different file (Scripts/Controllers/HomeController.js)

`AspnetMvcAngularJs.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);`

When the app is run, it doesn't seem to recognise `AspnetMvcAngularJs`.

Any pointers on what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**
While the below answers are excellent, I had noted something of vital importance.

**The order in which the files are accessed, matters**

E.g. I have used `bundles` in ASP.NET-MVC and the order should be like below:

`bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/definitions").
                Include("~/Scripts/AspnetMvcAngularJs.js").
                IncludeDirectory("~/Scripts/Controllers", "*.js"));`

This defines the `*.js` file that contain the `angular module` first and then includes the other `*.js` controller files.

The mistake I did was calling the controller files first. So the runtime threw an error specifying no such module was available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access to the defined modules with the same `angular.module` syntax but without specifying the dependencies of the module. In this case you'll get back the defined module and then u can use it to create controllers or other angular components out of it.

```
angular.module('AspnetMvcAngularJs').controller('HomeController',['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);)
```

Comment: Can't we separate that in to two files and put ?

Comment: you can separate into two files.

Comment: this: `angular.module('AspnetMvcAngularJs', [])` will create a module, while this: `angular.module('AspnetMvcAngularJs')` will return with the defined module

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quote from the [original angular doc on module](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module):

> **Creation versus Retrieval**
>
> Beware that using `angular.module('myModule',[])` will create the module `myModule` and overwrite any existing module
>   named `myModule`.
>
> Use `angular.module('myModule')` to retrieve an existing
>   module.

What `angular.module()` returns, whether you use the creation syntax or the retrieving syntax, is the module of `angular.Module` type, of which the methods `controller(), service(), directive(), value(), factory()` etc all return the module itself. Therefore, you can chain them together like the following:

```
angular.module('myModule', []).
     value('a', 123).
     controller( 'myController', function( $scope ) {...})
     factory('a', function() { return 123; }).
     directive('directiveName', ...).
     filter('filterName', ...);
```

You can also assign the module to a variable, and then access the module through the variable later:

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
// add some directives and services
myModule.service('myService', ...);
myModule.directive('myDirective', ...);
```

Module creation and module access codes can be put in separate files.

Comment: great answer. Thanks.:)